# Convert Class <capture of ?> to Class <T>

Tags: java, enums

I have an object which I am using reflection to create the Class object.

I am trying to convert an Enum field to its valueOf, but I do not know what Enum class it is.

Currently, I am just checking if the object is each Enum like this:

```
Class<?> t = obj.getType();

if (t == MyEnumA.class) {
   value = MyEnumA.valueOf(v)
} else if (t == MyEnumB.class) {
   value = MyEnumB.valueOf(v)
} else if ...
```

I currently have several different Enum classes, and as I add more I have to add a new else-if block for that new Enum.

I want to use something like this:

```
if (t.isEmun()) {
   value = Enum.valueOf(t, v);
}
```

But I have an error:

```
Required type: Class<T>
Provided type: Class<capture of ?>
```

How do I convert my `Class<capture of ?>` to `Class<T>`?

Comment: is this what you looking for https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getEnumConstants()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `asSubclass()` to safely cast:

```
value = Enum.valueOf(t.asSubclass(Enum.class), v);
```